# Too many arguments for open()

Tags: c++, gcc, file-io

I'm in the process of open sourcing some code which was written by myself and a few other individuals. In one of the code segments written by one of the other individuals, I am seeing the following:

```
open(filePath, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
open(filePath, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

Some how, this compiled on their system when we needed to execute it. However, on my system, GCC complains that `open()` is being passed too many arguments (which from my perspective, is accurate, as open only accepts 2 or 3 arguments to my knowledge). I'm also rather confused as to why `O_RDONLY | O_CREAT` and `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT` are both being passed in the same call to open.

While I wait to hear back from the other developer, does anyone have an idea as to why there are 4 arguments in this call to `open()`?

Comment: Looks a lot like some version control revision merge went wrong in there, doesn't it?

Comment: I did find a man page for open(3) that takes a vararg list.  Not sure why, but there it is.  http://linux.die.net/man/3/open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the POSIX standard, the C interface to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is declared as:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

Now, you're only supposed to provide one extra argument, but there's nothing the compiler can do to stop you providing more.  If you're compiling with C++, then it could be that you have overloaded declarations of `open()`:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag);
int open(const char *path, int oflag, mode_t mode);
```

This would more accurately reflect what is expected.  There are definitely some issues to be resolved implementing that, but it could be done.

So, the compilation probably worked on one machine because it was using the 'official' declaration with variable length argument list.  On your system, you seem to be better constrained.

The original code is broken.  Fix it.  And fix it in the new code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it compiled + executed on their system, but not mine. I should have remembered the potential for varArgs to result in such conditions.

Comment: The strange thing in my case is that in Eclipse CDT there is not such error and it's working perfectly fine. I'm currently moving to the QtCreator and use qmake for building my project. This error occurs there. Any idea what might be the problem with qmake and open()?

Comment: @rbaleksandar: what normally happens with the code shown in the question is that the second `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT` is treated as the 'mode' for the file, so your file, if it is created, ends up with weird permissions.  It 'works', but it doesn't do what is expected.  As for not getting a compilation error — that's normal.  On most systems, you won't get a compilation error for abusing `open()`, so learn not to abuse it without relying on the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The people who sent you that code just messed up.  Either the second or thrid argument should be removed, depending on what you want to do with the file.  For more info, see the [man page for open()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open).